# Regex for /etc/passwd Content

Tags: command-line, bash, regex, passwd

I have a collection files from many systems in my enterprise in a store directory (/store/) and I wanted to find all of the passwd files and cat them out to a single file. Intuitively, the command I came up with and use is:

```
find /store/ -name passwd -type f  -exec cat {} + > all_passwds.txt
```

But this also collects the /etc/passwd file that are binary files (I am assuming that some systems symlink to busybox or something).  I really just want text-based passwd files.

My next thought is that maybe I could find all /etc/passwd files and pull regex matches.  I have been trying for a couple of hours to create a regex that will match the passwd format.

Any help on either creating a regex that will match /etc/passwd files or how to ensure that the command above only grabs text passwd files would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13659891/6005145)

Comment: +1 ... although rather than using `grep -Iq .` as a test and then conditionally forking another `-exec cat {} \;` for each matching file, it might make more sense to use grep itself to do the catting, by using the empty string as a universal match ex. `-exec grep -IFh "" {} +`